# Installing software in home directory instead of /usr/bin/ in a server

Tags: python-2.7, installation, home-directory

I'm running my Python codes in a server to which I have been connected via ssh. I would like to however, update/install few external libraries for Python.

Since I am not the sudo user, I am not able to do the usual

```
pip install ....
```

as I get the error, for example when I tried installing `pyfits`:

```
 error: could not create '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyfits': Permission denied
```

Now, there are two questions, for which I have been trying to find answers for:

1. How do I update/install new libraries in my home directory instead of the default /usr/bin/..../ ?
2. How do I make the software (Python in this case) to understand that I have installed the new library in my home directory ?

Comment: Have you tried to create virtualenv and then run pip in it?

Comment: I have not tried that, but I suppose if I create a virtualenv, then I need to do it everytime I login. Is there a permanent solution ?

Comment: Nope, you don't have to create it everytime you login. Check [this](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv) guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install modules in your HOME directory -
`pip install --user $PACKAGE_NAME`
should do the trick.
This will install package in $HOME/.local/bin/$PACKAGE and the rest of package in $HOME/.local/lib/pythonx/site-packages/.

Comment: Will Python automatically recognise that the new package has been installed and is in home directory ?

Comment: yes. For testing I installed the pip package named "a". It was installed in `'/home/markroxor/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/a.pyc'.
`